# Replacement for Excel

Tags: webapp-rec

We have a small team of 20 people who use basic spreadsheet functions to share daily reports between us for our clients.  We'd like to switch to a web-based product vs using Excel.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 9):

[Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/tour1.html)

> **Upload your existing files.**
>   Google Docs accepts most popular file formats, including DOC, XLS, ODT, ODS, RTF, CSV, PPT, etc. So go ahead and upload your existing files.
>
> **Familiar desktop feel makes editing a breeze.**
>   Just click the toolbar buttons to bold, underline, indent, change font or number format, change cell background color and so on.
>
> **Share instantly.**
>   Anyone you've invited to either edit or view your document, spreadsheet or presentation can access it as soon as they sign in.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Docs.com](http://docs.com/), which is Microsoft's free online service. You won't have to do any kind of conversion with the existing spreadsheet documents.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a webapp, but i would recommended [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), it's free and I think it should satisfy your needs.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd recommend this desktop option rather any available web application options?

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Zoho Sheet**](http://sheet.zoho.com/login.do?serviceurl=%2Fhome.do)

- Share, don't attach
- Collaborative editing of spreadsheets
- Macros and Pivot Tables
- Build Mashups

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google's Marketplace to see new integrated apps that might fit your needs.  Due to customer requests, we created an app for customers who manage commissions spreadsheets on Google Spreadsheets (previously could only use MS Excel)--check it out here:  [OneClick Commissions](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=8904+11372811770063118806).  Note that you need to have a Google Apps login to take advantage of this integrated app.